# Where is the config file for Protractor / webdriver-manager / Selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I've installed Protractor and Selenium so I can do E2E testing with my JavaScript.  When I launch Selenium (`webdriver-manager start`) I get the following line

> 10:20:17.961 INFO - Default driver
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS,
>   ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}]
>   does not match with current platform: MAC

How do I change the default driver?  I see lots of references to config files, but I can not find any place where people give the name and location of the Selenium startup config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place where you define the Selenium starup config file is

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
```

See https://letmedothat.wordpress.com/category/protractor-2/

Summary of the linked blog page:

```
npm -version
npm install -g protractor
protractor --version
Java -version
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
cd C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example
protractor conf.js
```

Updating driver is often necessary, running the selenium server, changing directory and then executing the test from command prompt is often boring and annoying. So, I wrote a simple batch file to make the process easy. Because, I am lazy. Simply copy these commands, change the file directory and save as .bat file. To execute the test simply double click and you are done.

```
@echo on
set errorlevel = 0
::WebDriver update
start /b webdriver-manager update
    If %errorlevel% neq 0 set &quot;job=webdriver-manager update&quot; exit/b &amp;goto err
    ::exit/b 

::Start selenium  server
start /b webdriver-manager start
    If %errorlevel% neq 0 set &quot;job=webdriver-manager start&quot; exit/b &amp;goto err

::Change directory
cd D:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example
    If %errorlevel% neq 0 set &quot;job=changing directory&quot; exit/b &amp;goto err

::Start running tests
protractor conf.js
    If %errorlevel% neq 0 set &quot;job=protractor conf.js&quot; exit/b &amp;goto err

:err
    echo ERROR: %job% execution failed with error.

pause
```

Comment: On the mac it's /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor

Comment: @EricLeschinski Thank you sir for the kind edit and time. That's my blog and I maintain it. Will try to put the gist of the link in future.